# setContentOffset not working after updating data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` and when the user scrolls to the top, I want to add a bunch of cells above the first cell without affecting the current scroll position (just like iMessage)

I know I can use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` to do this without reloading the data, but I just want to do it the simplest way possible first. So I am overwriting the data and calling `reload`, then calling `setContentOffset`, but no matter what I set the offset to, the table always reverts to the top.

```
// in an NSNotification handler
//...
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

  // get old content height
  CGSize oldContentSize = self.tableView.contentSize;
  NSLog(@"old content height: %f", oldContentSize.height);

  // update tableView data
  self.messages = updatedMessages;
  [self.tableView reloadData];

  // get new content height
  CGSize newContentSize = self.tableView.contentSize;
  NSLog(@"new content height: %f", newContentSize.height);

  // move to user scroll position
  CGPoint newContentOffset = CGPointMake(0, newContentSize.height - oldContentSize.height);
  [self.tableView setContentOffset:newContentOffset];
});
```

When I run this I get:

```
old content height: 557.765625
new content height: 1249.050781
```

but the tableView reverts to the top instead of maintaining its scroll position.

I found that if I call `[self.tableView setContentOffset:newContentOffset animated:YES];` It always scrolls down to the correct position, but the movement is unacceptable.

How can I maintain the scroll position after reloading the tableView data?

I've looked at these:

[setContentOffset only works if animated is set to YES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917460/setcontentoffset-only-works-if-animated-is-set-to-yes)

[UIScrollView setContentOffset: animated: not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882232/uiscrollview-setcontentoffset-animated-not-working)

[UITableView contentOffSet is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222186/uitableview-contentoffset-is-not-working-properly)

but their solutions don't work in my case.

Comment: How about  [self.tableView setContentOffset:newContentOffset animated:NO];;

Comment: Ok, thank you very much : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:newContentOffset animated:NO]
```